# Rails/Backbone .pdf rendering on client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

For the sake of separating concerns, we made this app such as Rails Api on server side and Backbone/Marionette on the client side. Today, we are trying to send a freshly generated invoice to our users thanks to a dedicated route. The idea behind it is the following: An user click invoice, a request is made to the server, the server sends the file and the client displays/allow to download it.

On the server side, the invoice method looks like:

```
def invoice
  @order = current_user.orders.with_uuid(params[:id])
  if @order
    @order.order_attachment.with_document_file do |file|
      File.open(file.path, 'r') do |f|
        send_data f.read, :filename => 'report.pdf',
                          :type => 'application/pdf',
                          :disposition => 'attachment'
      end
    end
  else
    render nothing: true, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

On the client side, we get the data with this function to test our code:

```
$.get("#{config.apiRootUrl}user/things/#{@model.attributes.id}/invoice", dataType: 'binary', processData: false)
  .complete (response) ->
    console.log response
  .fail (response) ->
    console.log response
```

The response looks like (raw data extract since it's way longer):

```
%PDF-1.4
%ÿÿÿÿ
1 0 obj
<< /Creator <feff0050007200610077006e>
/Producer <feff0050007200610077006e>
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [5 0 R]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Length 8033
>>
stream
q

q
128.000 0 0 57.000 36.000 699.000 cm
/I1 Do
Q
1 w
/DeviceRGB CS
1.000 1.000 1.000 SCN
36.000 649.000 m
191.856 649.000 l
S
[ ] 0 d
```

So, here comes the question. Keeping in mind that we can not use different approach for the .pdf download such as giving the client an url to download directly the .pdf file and considering the previous data, is there a way to:

- Specify things better on server side, so the browser understands it is a pdf file instead of raw data?
- Use client side fancy librairy that rebuilds the pdf from the raw data once received by the client?
- Any other solution solving this problem.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: redirect to invoice.pdf ? with `disposition: 'inline'`

Answer (score 0):

[Not tested!]
In the controller I would wrap the rendering part in a block

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf {
      ...<your code>...

      }
    end
```

and on the client request invoice.pdf without specifying a dataType

Answer (score 0):

For those looking how to handle response containing a .pdf from a rest api, the answer was on client side. We had to create that blob object based on the api response to 're-build' the pdf on client side. Here is a sample of what we used to achieve this purpose:

```
   $.get("#{config.apiRootUrl}user/orders/#{@model.attributes.uuid}/invoice")
      .complete (response) ->
        blob = new Blob([response.responseText], type: 'application/pdf')
        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        $a = $('<a />', {
          'href': url,
          'download': "#{Date.now()}.pdf",
          'text': "click"
        }).hide().appendTo("body")[0].click()
```